# Find rows where string contains certain character at specific place

Tags: postgresql

I have a field in my database, that contains 10 characters: 
Fx: 1234567891

I want to look for the rows where the field has eg. the numbers 8 and 9 in places 5 and 6

So for example, 
if the rows are

a) `1234567891`
b) `1234897891`
c) `1234877891`

I only want b) returned in my select. 
The type of the field is string/character varying.

I have tried using:

```
where field like '%89%'
```

but that won't work, because I need it to be 89 at a specific place in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution would be

```
WHERE substr(field, 8, 2) = '89'
```

If the positions are not adjacent, you end up with two conditions joined with `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to evaluate the single character using the underscore(_) character.  So you should be able to use it as follows.

```
where field like '____89%'
```